# Let $A$ be a bounded operator defined on $X$ a Banach space, and $R(A)$ a Banach space. Then $\overline{R(A')}=N(A)^{\perp}$.

Tags: functional-analysis

I am able to prove one of the contentions, which in fact is quite easy to see, $\overline{R(A')} \subseteq N(A)^{\perp}$. But to prove the other contention, it is probably necessary to use the hypothesis that $R(A)$ is Banach, but I cannot see where or why will this be relevant.

Comment: Possibly related: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_range_theorem

Comment: Since $R(A)$ is a Banach space, it is a closed subspace of $X$. Hence, the closed range theorem implies that $R(A')$ is closed as well and it also supplies your identity. Do you want a simpler proof?